# Basic question on exactness of commutative diagrams.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I thought I understand what a commutative diagram meant until I saw these examples.

$$H \overset{j}{\longrightarrow} G \overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow} G/H$$

where $j$ is inclusion and $\phi$ is the canonical map. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. This is an example of an exact diagram but I don't understand what exactly $j$ or "inclusion" means in this instance OR how to interpret the image of $j$.

Other commutative diagrams begin and end with $0$ and there are no functions above the arrows connecting $0$ to elements or elements to $0$. What does the $0$ denote and why is it there? I think it has something to do with the condition of exactness and implying injectiveness/surjectiveness but I am wondering if there is any other meaning. Is there a function implicitly defined but not stated when writing $0\to G$ for example?

Thank you.

Comment: $j:H\to G$ is defined by $j(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$. The image of $j$, $j(H)$, is $H$.

Comment: While this diagram is "commutative," it is trivially so, so it is not really about commutative diagrams, but about exactness.

Comment: In the category of groups, we usually use $1$ rather than $0$, using $0$ in the category of abelian groups, where we usually write our operation as $+$.

Comment: Thank you @Zircht, I am now confident about the first diagram. I should have known because of the exactness condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Using $1$ for a "zero object" can be confusing too...

Comment: Which is why we don't call it a zero object, but a final object. @Pece

Comment: @ThomasAndrews When an object is both initial and final, it is pretty standard to call it a zero object. But I agree that the trivial group is usually denoted $1$ in a non abelian context.

Comment: In an abelian category, it is called zero. In the category of groups, it is always called $1$, in all my experience. @Pece

Answer (score 1):

I seems as you mixing up exactness with commutation. Commutation is just a relation between morphisms in diagrams, while exactness is a condition on sequences of morphisms.

An inclusion $H\overset{j}\hookrightarrow G$ is just the trivial function $j(h)=h$.

Exactness in $G$ is that the image of $j$, that is $H$ itself, is equal to the kernel of $\phi$: $\phi(g)=0 \Leftrightarrow g\in H$.

A *diagram* is commutative if and only if every different combination of arrows from one object (group) to an other results in the same morphism (as compositions).
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>\alpha>> C\\
@V\phi V V\# @VV\psi V\\
B @>>\beta> D
\end{CD}
This diagram is commutative if and only if

$(1)\quad\psi\alpha=\beta\phi$

The diagram is just a picture describing $(1)$.

The '$0$' denote the simplest group with only one element. That the *sequence*
$0\rightarrow H\overset{j}\rightarrow G$ is exact in $H$ just means that the kernel of $j$ is equal to the group $0$. The arrow without name refers to the unique morphism from $0$ to $H$.